# Elixir map value not updating

Tags: elixir

I wrote a function in Elixir that creates a map then tried changing the value of one of its keys but it doesn't seem to want to update.

```
defmodule KV do
    def test() do
        map = %{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
        IO.inspect map.foo
        %{map | foo: "baz"}
        IO.inspect map.foo
    end
end

KV.test()
```

What I expect to appear after compiling the code is this:

```
"bar"
"baz"
```

But what I actually get is this:

```
"bar"
"bar"
```

However, when I tried just typing it on the iex shell it does what it's supposed to do:

```
iex(1)> map = %{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
%{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
iex(2)> %{map | foo: "baz"}
%{foo: "baz", hello: "world"}
```

I've tried a number of other methods to update the value but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elixir maps are immutable. `%{map | foo: "baz"}` creates a new map with the updated value, but you need to assign the new map to `map` if you want to access the new value using `map.foo`:

```
map = %{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
IO.inspect map.foo
map = %{map | foo: "baz"}
IO.inspect map.foo
```

The behavior in the REPL is exactly the same if you try to print `map.foo` after your second line of input:

```
iex(1)> map = %{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
%{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
iex(2)> map.foo
"bar"
iex(3)> %{map | foo: "baz"}
%{foo: "baz", hello: "world"}
iex(4)> map.foo
"bar"
iex(5)> map = %{map | foo: "baz"}
%{foo: "baz", hello: "world"}
iex(6)> map.foo
"baz"
```